# How to uninstall pip3 from home directory?

Tags: uninstall, pip

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I was messing around in my home directory and ran `pip3 install --upgrade pip` trying to upgrade pip3. I got this warning:

```
WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/home/my_username/.local/bin'
which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, 
if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-22.0.4
```

When I checked my pip3 version it says I'm still in 20.0.2:

```
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

How should I uninstall this pip3 from my home directory?

Comment: "pip" is the old binary. As said: your new pip is not in PATH. What happens if you call `/home/my_username/.local/bin/pip --version` (replace my_username with yours and mind the dot before .local)

Comment: @kanehekili calling that gives me ```pip 22.0.4 from /home/my_username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've updated pip and pip installed in your local bin directory. Since that pip is not in your path, you could simply delete them locally.(or leave them, they won't hurt)
As your test showed, your "update" has been made locally.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

should do it for the whole system. Then `pip --version` should give you the  updated version without using your local path.

Comment: Thank you. which command should I use to uninstall it locally?

Comment: You used pip to upgrade locally. You did not "install" anything, just copied some code in your ".local/bin" directory. Open a terminal an use `rm` to delete the files... There is no pip command to remove a local pip update.